# Creating shortcuts to the same web app from 2 different chrome profiles override each other

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, web-app

In Chrome, I'm trying to create 2 shortcuts of the same app (`mail.google.com`) from 2 different profiles.

The problem is that the last shortcut overrides the previous.

In Ubuntu it worked OK - got 2 different mail shortcuts for 2 different profiles.

Any idea how to fix it? Perhaps duplicate and tinker with the shortcut itself? Thanks.

(Perhaps it's a chrome question?)

Comment: Posted on superuser as well - https://superuser.com/questions/1629530/creating-shortcuts-to-the-same-web-app-from-2-different-chrome-profiles-override

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Will wait for some answers and will flag the irrelevant one.